# Can't use different instruments in my class

Tags: java, class, audio, midi

for a little project at school, we 've to make a little beatbox software. I 've built this, but i have 2 problem and i can't understand where is the error:

1) the first 2, and the last instruments row of checkboxes doesn't work. I've mapped for each checkbox an instrument code, but it seems to be ignored.

2) A lot of instrument sounds all the same (eg. maracas, whistle, low conga). I've tried to print out the code assigned to the cheackboxes and seems to be right. Why does it behave like this?

here's the complete class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;


public class MusicBox {
JPanel mainpanel;
ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxList;
Sequencer sequencer;
Sequence sequence;
Track track;
JFrame theFrame;

private JFileChooser chooser;

String[] ListaStrumenti = {"Metronome Tic", "Laser" , "Bass Drum", "Closed Hi-Hat", "Open Hi-Hat",
        "Acoustic Snare", "Crash Cymbal", "Hand Clap", "High Tom",
        "Hi Bongo", "Maracas", "Whistle", "Low Conga", "Cowbell",
        "Vibraslap", "Low-mid Tom", "High Agogo", "Open Hi Conga","Claves" , "Splash Cymbal", "Ride Bell", "Tamburine","Surdu"};
int[] strumenti = { 32,27,35, 42, 46, 38, 49, 39, 50, 60, 70, 72, 64, 56, 58,
        47, 67, 63, 75, 49 , 53, 54, 87 };



public void buildGUI() {
    chooser = new JFileChooser( new File( System.getProperty("user.home") ));

    theFrame = new JFrame("beatbox multimediale");
    theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    JPanel background = new JPanel(layout);
    background.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

    checkboxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
    Box buttonBox = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

    JButton start = new JButton("Pulisci box");
    start.addActionListener(new StartListener());
    buttonBox.add(start);

    JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    stop.addActionListener(new StopListener());
    buttonBox.add(stop);

    JButton uptempo = new JButton("Aumenta Battiti");
    uptempo.addActionListener(new UpListener());
    buttonBox.add(uptempo);

    JButton downtempo = new JButton("Diminuisci Battiti");
    downtempo.addActionListener(new DownListener());
    buttonBox.add(downtempo);

    JButton serialize = new JButton("Salva Beat");
    serialize.addActionListener(new SalvaListener());
    buttonBox.add(serialize);

    JButton restore = new JButton("Carica Beat");
    restore.addActionListener(new CaricaListener());
    buttonBox.add(restore);



    GridLayout gridn= new GridLayout(23,1);
    gridn.setVgap(8);
    gridn.setHgap(1);
    mainpanel=new JPanel(gridn);




    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        mainpanel.add(new Label(ListaStrumenti[i]));

    }// end for loop

    background.add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START, buttonBox);
    background.add(BorderLayout.WEST, mainpanel);

    theFrame.getContentPane().add(background);

    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(23, 16);
    grid.setVgap(5);
    grid.setHgap(1);
    mainpanel = new JPanel(grid);
    background.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainpanel);

    for (int i = 0; i < 368; i++) {
        JCheckBox c = new JCheckBox();
        c.setSelected(false);
        checkboxList.add(c);
        c.addActionListener(new CBListener());
        mainpanel.add(c);
    }// end for loop

    setUpMidi();

    theFrame.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);
    theFrame.pack();
    theFrame.setVisible(true);
}// end buildgui

public void setUpMidi() {
    try {
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();
        sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        track = sequence.createTrack();
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(128);
    }// end try
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }// end catch
}// end setupmidi

public void buildTrackandStart() {
    int[] trackList = null;
    sequence.deleteTrack(track);
    track = sequence.createTrack();
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) { //da aumentare il numero degli strumenti
        trackList = new int[16];
        int key = strumenti[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            JCheckBox jc = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(j + (16 * i));  //prende la      checkbox per ogni strumento
            if (jc.isSelected()) {
                trackList[j] = key;
                System.out.println(trackList[j]);
            }// end if
            else {
                trackList[j] = 0;
            }// end else
            // jc.setEnabled(false);
        }// end inner for loop

        creaTraccie(trackList);
        track.add(CreaEvento(176, 1, 127, 0, 16));
    }// end outer for loop

    track.add(CreaEvento(192, 9, 1, 0, 15));

    try {
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        sequencer.setLoopCount(sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        sequencer.start();
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(128);
    }// end try
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }// end catch
}// end buildtrackandstart

public class CBListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        buildTrackandStart();
    }

}

public class StartListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        sequencer.stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) { //da aumentare il numero degli strumenti

            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                JCheckBox jc = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(j + (16 * i));  //prende la checkbox per ogni strumento

                jc.setSelected(false);
            }// end inner for loop
        }
    }// end actionperformed
}// end inner class start

public class StopListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        sequencer.stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) { //da aumentare il numero degli strumenti

            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                JCheckBox jc = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(j + (16 * i));  //prende la checkbox per ogni strumento

                //  jc.setEnabled(true);
            }// end inner for loop
        }

    }// end actionperformed
}// end inner class stop

public class UpListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        float tempoFactor = sequencer.getTempoFactor();
        sequencer.setTempoFactor((float) (tempoFactor * 1.03));
    }// end actionperformed
}// end inner class uptempo

public class DownListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        float tempoFactor = sequencer.getTempoFactor();
        sequencer.setTempoFactor((float) (tempoFactor * .97));
    }// end actionperformed
}// end innerclass downtempo

public class SalvaListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        boolean[] checkboxState = new boolean[368];

        for (int i = 0; i < 368; i++) {
            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if (check.isSelected()) {
                checkboxState[i] = true;
            }// end if
        }// end for loop

        try {
            int result = chooser.showSaveDialog(MusicBox.this.theFrame);
            if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(        chooser.getSelectedFile()
 //  new File(   "Checkbox.ser")
                );
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
                os.writeObject(checkboxState);
            }

        }// end try
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }// end catch
    }// end actionperformed
}// end innerclass SalvaListener

public class CaricaListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        boolean[] checkboxState = null;
        try {
            int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(MusicBox.this.theFrame);
            if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream(
                        chooser.getSelectedFile()
//   new File(   "Checkbox.ser")
                );
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(filein);
                checkboxState = (boolean[]) is.readObject();
            }
        }// end try
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }// end catch

        for (int i = 0; i < 368; i++) {
            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if (checkboxState[i]) {
                check.setSelected(true);
            }// end if
            else {
                check.setSelected(false);
            }// end else
        }// end for loop

        sequencer.stop();

    }// end actionperformed
}// end innerclass

public void loadFile(File file) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        reader.close();
    }// end try
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Non sono riuscito a caricare il file");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }// end catch
}// end loadfile

public void creaTraccie(int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        int key = list[i];

        if (key != 0) {
            track.add(CreaEvento(144, 9, key, 100, i));
            track.add(CreaEvento(128, 9, key, 100, i + 1));
        }// end if
    }// end for loop
}// end creaTraccie

public MidiEvent CreaEvento(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) {
    MidiEvent event = null;
    try {
        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
        event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);
    }// end try
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }// end catch

    return event;

}// end CreaEvento

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MusicBox().buildGUI();
}

}//
// end class beatbox
```

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. The last row of checkboxes are working for me. And maracas, whitle, and low conga seem to be making different sounds.

Comment: ????? Why not to me?? What it could be?? The first 2 rows are working too?? Btw ty for the answer

Comment: i've tried on a different pc and it gives me the same problems!

Comment: Hmm...that's certainly interesting...I have to go to school in a few minutes. I'll look at your program again when I get home.